# Query returns content from previous functions

Tags: php, mysql

I have a Chat.php file containing everything query-related. Then there is a Core.php containing connection to database and basic functions used in Chat.php like "query" and "rows" which processes the "query" into array.

In Chat.php there are two functions, the second one printing content of the first when using print_r($this->rows());. checkForLastMessage() is supposed to check one table to see if there are new messages to be pulled from another table with function getNewMessages().

This is how it looks like:
Core.php

```
<?php
class Core
{
...
    public function query($sql)
    {
        $this->result = $this->db->query($sql);
    }

    public function rows()
    {
        for($x = 1; $x <= $this->db->affected_rows; $x++)
        {
            $this->rows[] = $this->result->fetch_assoc();
        }
        return $this->rows;
    }
}
```

Chat.php

```
<?php
class Chat extends Core
{
public function checkForLatestMessage($chatid, $iam)
    {
        $userinchat='for'.$iam;
        $this->query("SELECT anonchat.$userinchat FROM anonchat WHERE anonchat.chatid=$chatid");

        $printarray = Array();
        $printaray = '';

        foreach( $this->rows() as $id )
        {
            $printarray[] = $id[$userinchat];
        }

        if($printarray[0] != '')
        {
            $this->getNewMessages($chatid, $printarray[0]);
        }
    }
    public function getNewMessages($chatid, $requiredMessages)
    {
        $this->query("SELECT anonmessage.content, anonmessage.timeposted FROM anonmessage WHERE anonmessage.messageid IN ($requiredMessages) ORDER BY anonmessage.timeposted ASC");

        print_r($this->rows());
    }
```

The last print_r contains elements from the previous function. I don't know why that is.

Edit. This is the output:

> Array ( [0] => Array ( [for1] => 2,4,6 ) [1] => Array ( [content] =>
>   Message 2 [timeposted] => 2017-08-04 16:12:34 ) [2] => Array (
>   [content] => Message 4 [timeposted] => 2017-08-04 16:12:48 ) [3] =>
>   Array ( [content] => Message 6 [timeposted] => 2017-08-04 16:13:03 ) )

Element [0] of array (the one with "for1") is remaining from previous function.

Comment: what you mean `print_r contains elements from the previous function`  Show us db schema, sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `$this->rows` is only updated when your query returns something. Are you sure it does? Oh, and you're only _adding_ new array elements at the end, I don't see you remove any content.

Comment: Here is output (element [0] is remaining from first function): Array ( [0] => Array ( [for1] => 2,4,6 ) [1] => Array ( [content] => Message 2 [timeposted] => 2017-08-04 16:12:34 ) [2] => Array ( [content] => Message 4 [timeposted] => 2017-08-04 16:12:48 ) [3] => Array ( [content] => Message 6 [timeposted] => 2017-08-04 16:13:03 ) )

Comment: @Marvin, how would I go about removing the content from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, you're initializing the class property $this->rows in the first method and then the 2nd method is appending to it. You need to reset $this->rows before adding to it.

```
public function getNewMessages($chatid, $requiredMessages)
{
    $this->rows = null;
    $this->query("SELECT anonmessage...");

    print_r($this->rows());
}
```

Or better yet, reset the variable in the *query()* method. That way you don't have to do it each time.

Please don't take offense when I say that this is a bad design.

- You're trying to write your own DAL (Data Abstraction Layer). This is a very complicated task and there are already lots of implementations out there. The Core class is going to become massive, complicated, and unwieldy when you try to adapt it to a dozen other classes.
- PHP only supports a single inheritance so right off the bat you shot your self in the foot because any class that needs DB interactions will have to extend Core and you won't be able to extend anything else.

Consider keeping things simple for now and let each method handle their own queries and DB interactions. Focus on major concepts like DRY, encapsulation and keeping your classes focused on their responsibility.

Ex. checkForLatestMessage() what is this supposed to do? It sounds like should check for messages and then return a boolean (true|false) but instead it is calling getNewMessages() which outputs some data.

I don't know enough about your application to really suggest something useful but this feels a bit better than the path you're heading down. Notice we're not inheriting from Core so you're free to inherit from something else. The methods are concise and do what they say. You'd probably also save a few lines of code this way and it's easier to read.

```
<?php
class Chat
{
    public function hasNewMessages($chatid, $iam)
    {
        // Query using PDO properly 

        return (bool)$hasNewMessages;
    }

    public function getNewMessages($chatid, $requiredMessages)
    {
        // Query using PDO properly 

        // An array of data or objects
        return $messages;
    }
 }


 /******** Client Code ***********/
 $chat = new Chat();

 if ($chat->hasNewMessages()) {
    foreach ($chat->getNewMessages($id, $required) as $message) {
        // $message
    }
 }
```

Just some of my thoughts... good luck.

Comment: Thank you, your solution works great (added it in query function). I am all over the place but I was thinking about doing something as you suggested. As far as the specific function, it only calls the other one if it's not empty, otherwise it will return false, 0 or something.